# windows phone webview resize

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, webview, resize

I am making a windows phone 8 app.
I am using a webbrowser(in the app)to show the user a link to a page. After the user clicked it, he should see the webcontrol on the entire screen.
Currently I have:

```
private void webcontrol_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("xxxxxxx"))
   {
      webcontrol.Width = this.Width;
      webcontrol.Height = this.Height;
      webcontrol.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
BTW: I get into the code, it just doesn't execute it like i want.

Comment: Your code is working  perfectly for me . Also try by using Browser navigating event

Comment: I just tried it on the webcontrol_navigating event and still isn't working.
Did you set anything else?

Comment: Include your xaml layout in question

Comment: thx for the aid you wanted to give, but i found a workaround by using another webbrowser element which has the full size, and just pass on the right link to that element.